# PHP SQLite3 not working online but on localhost

Tags: php, html, sqlite

As the title says, I cannot get my few scripts to run online on the server.

I can include the php files, swell as the database '*.db' to this thread, if it would help...

I was working on localhost with XAMPP to test out everything, before "going online", but that somehow seems to be the problem...
The scripts in php and sqlite are very basic:

I have a small database saved as 'y2018.db' which consists of information about conferences (including e.g. name, start date, end date, topics, URL,...). A php "homepage" lists every entry in this database. Another php file lets the user add entries to this file...

About the server:

-SQLite Version is 3.7.13

-php Version is 5.4.45

-The 'y2018.db' file has permission to read/write/execute by anybody.

I am currently stuck at the point, that the php-file shows anything until the part, where it should connect. No (!) error is shown, which is why I could not look for any troubleshooting...

I hope you can help me?

Comment: Is the sqlite extension enabled on the production server? You probably don't see any errors because it's configured not to display them, but you should be able to find them in the error log.

Comment: I am not sure, how to check it, but when typing php -phpinfo \(\)\; into the bash, it says:
sqlite3
SQLite3 support => enabled

and could you tell me, how to review the error log?

Answer (score 0):

You should check file permission also for all path to your database.

`chmod -R 775` from server root